# Is it possible to save plotly table as png?

Tags: python, plotly

I found this very cool and usefull way ( I am very new to Python) to do tables.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['Column1', 'Column2'],
                line_color='rgb(255,255,255)',
                fill_color='rgb(230,100,100)',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], # 1st column
                       [95, 85, 75, 95]], # 2nd column
               line_color='rgb(255,255,255)',
               fill_color= 'rgb(255,255,255)',
               align='left'))
])

fig.update_layout(width=500, height=300)
fig.show()
```

Unfortunately I could not find a way to save this as a png, is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `write_image()` function. See the documentation: https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/

So that would be: `write_image("image.png")`

You can save it as loads of other formats too including bmp, jpeg, pdf

Comment: Well thank you very much. Now I have the problem that it can't find orca... but that is not a big problem at this point! Thank you very much!

Comment: @KingDingeling  It does require a separate installation. Maybe `python -m pip install orca` or `conda install -c plotly plotly-orca==1.2.1 psutil requests` on conda?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'write_image', It is working for other figures, but not for Table